# Cakephp search with postgres similarity

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to build a search funtion in my website and ssort the results by best match. I am using postgres and would wan to use `similarity()` to get a score.
To have the best match I use `regexp_matches()` 
Now everything works as expected and after using `bind()` to reduce the risk of sql injection, I get results as I would expect.

The issue I am having is with brackets since they wont be escaped and this causes errors.

my code so far:

```
$search = 'Some Query';
$query->find('active')
        ->select([
            'Shops.id',
            'Shops.name',
            'score' => $query->newExpr()->add(
                "similarity(Shops.name, :search)"
            ),
            'regexp' => $query->newExpr()->add(
                "regexp_matches(lower(Shops.name), lower(:search))"
            ),
        ])
        ->bind(':search', $search, 'string')
        ->contain([
            'Currencies' => function (Query $q) {
                return $q->find('active');
            },
        ])
        ->order(['score' => 'DESC'])
        ->limit(ShopsTable::LIMIT_SEARCH);
```

**Is there a good practice to make the query save?**

**Note:** Before this I was using the crud lookup action which would escape the search query correctly.

With the current code:
Some Shop - works
S'ome Shop - works
S"ome Shop - works
Some( Shop - does not work
Some{ Shop - does not work